# Necessary and sufficient condition for equality of two tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $v_1, v_2 \in V; w_1, w_2 \in W$. What is necessary and sufficient condition for equality $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$ in $V \otimes W$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the following cases:

1. If $w_1 = 0$ then $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$ iff $v_2 = 0$ or $w_2 = 0$.
2. If $w_1 \neq 0$ and $w_2 = c w_1$ for some $c \in \mathbb{F}$ then $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$ iff $cv_2 = v_1$.
3. If $w_1,w_2$ are linearly independent then $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$ iff $v_1 = v_2 = 0$

To see why, remember that if $(e_i)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(f_j)$ is a basis of $W$ then $(e_i \otimes f_j)$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$ and use this to analyze each case.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer has given the standard "linear-algebra" perspective.  Another way to answer this question (more common in functional analysis and abstract algebra) is via the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) that defines a tensor product.

> The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$
> 2. For every $f \in (V \otimes W)^*$, $f(v_1 \otimes w_1) = f(v_2 \otimes w_2)$
> 3. For every bilinear form $f: V \times W \to \Bbb F$, $f(v_1,w_1) = f(v_2,w_2)$

From the above, "3" tends to be particularly useful.

For instance: take $v_1 = w_2 = e_1$ and $v_2 = w_1 = e_2$, where $e_1,e_2$ denote the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb R^2 = V = W$.  We can define the bilinear form $f:V \times W \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
f(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2,y_1e_1 + y_2e_2) = x_1y_2
$$
We see that $f(v_1,w_1) = 1$, whereas $f(v_2,w_2) = 0$.  Thus, $v_1 \otimes w_1$ and $v_2 \otimes w_2$ are distinct elements in $V \otimes W$.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a proof of 3) => 1)?

Comment: @Dole here's one I like: for every linear $f:V \otimes W \to \Bbb F$, the map $(v,w) \mapsto f(v \otimes w)$ is bilinear.  Thus, we find that $f(v_1 \otimes w_1) = f(v_2 \otimes w_2)$ for every linear $f:V \otimes W \to \Bbb F$.  This is enough to conclude that $v_1 \otimes w_1 = v_2 \otimes w_2$.