# When does restriction of scalars induce flat Modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a ring homomorphism, and let us consider $X$ to be a $Y$-module via restriction of scalars, i.e. given some $y\in Y$, this element acts on $X$ via $f(y)\cdot x$, for $x\in X$

I'm trying to determine what conditions we must put on $f$ in order for $X$ to be a flat $Y$-module. By definition, this means that given an injective morphism $m:N\rightarrow M$ of $Y$-modules, we have that $1\times m: X\otimes_Y N \rightarrow X\otimes M$ is also injective.

I did a bit of computation that seemed a bit off to me, and I just wanted a bit of a sanity check. To prove what conditions on $f$ would be necessary in order for $1\times m$ to be monic, suppose we had $x_1\otimes m(n_1)= x_2\otimes m(n_2)$. We want to see how we might obtain the equation $x_1\otimes n_1 = x_2\otimes n_2$.

I would like to prove this in a setting more general than vector spaces (really, I'd like to work in the category of sup-lattices, as found in Joyal-Tierney), but for now let's just follow the characterisation provided in the answer here: [Necessary and sufficient condition for equality of two tensor products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162556/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-equality-of-two-tensor-products)

Then, there are three cases in which $x_1\otimes m(n_1)= x_2\otimes m(n_2)$:

1. Suppose $m(n_1)\neq 0$, and $\exists y\in Y$ such that $y\cdot m(n_1)=m(n_2)$. Then this forces the relation that $f(y)\cdot x_2 = x_1$. Since $Y$-module morphisms respect the action, we have that $m(n_2)=y\cdot m(n_1)= m(y\cdot n_1)$, which implies that $n_2=y\cdot n_1$ since $m$ is injective. Since $f(y)\cdot x_2=x_1$, this means that $x_2\otimes n_2 = x_2\otimes y\cdot n_1 = f(y)\cdot x_2\otimes n_1 = x_1\otimes n_1$.
2. Suppose $m(n_1),m(n_2)$ are linearly independent. Then, $x_1=x_2=0$, which implies that $x_1\otimes n_1 = x_2\otimes n_2$.
3. Finally, suppose $m(n_1)=0$. Then, we have that either $m(n_2)=0$ or $x_2=0$. Since $m$ is monic, we have that $n_1=0$, and thus $x_1\otimes n_1=0$. If $m(n_2)=0$, then $n_2=0$ as well, and thus $x_2\otimes n_2=0$; and if $x_2=0$, then $x_2\otimes n_2=0$ as well.

---

This little computation seems to imply that restriction of scalars always induces a flat module in this way - is that right? But that seems strange. For instance, take the quotient map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. It is well-known that for $n>1$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not flat over $\mathbb{Z}$ since while $n:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, $x\mapsto nx$ is injective, the map $1\times n:\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}$ is not injective.

Have I done something silly in the process?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that linearly dependency is subtler when you work with rings.

You could have $m(n_1)\neq 0$ and $m(n_1),m(n_2)$ linearly dependent, but having $m(n_2)\neq y\cdot m(n_1)$ for all $y\in Y$.

For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $2,3$ are linearly dependent since $2.3-3.2=0$, but $2\neq m\cdot 3$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

(Also, I hope you know that even if your three cases work (for example in the case of vector spaces), it is not enough to prove injectivity of of $1\times m$, since an element of the tensor product is a **sum** of elementary tensors.)

What you need to prove is for all $\sum_i x_i\otimes n_i$, $\sum_i x_i\otimes m(n_i)=0$ implies $\sum_i x_i\otimes n_i=0$.

You hae compelte characterization of flat modules, but the easiest case to handle is when your module is finitely presented (ie isomorphic to $F/F'$, where $F$ is free of finite rank and $F'$ is finitely generated). In this case, flat is equivalent to finitely generated and projective (which is equivalent to : isomorphic to a direct factor a free module of finite rank)

Comment: Hmm... interesting. So just to be clear, the case-splitting suggested in the linked answer not quite correct, then? Because it assumes that linear dependence can be captured by Case 1, which is not true?

Comment: I guess I'm still not entirely comfortable with tensor products. I understand that an element of the tensor product is a sum of elementary tensors, but I can't quite see how that's not sufficient to demonstrate injectivity of $1\times m$ - how do we go about demonstrating injectivity of the maps of tensored modules in general? I've tried using the universal property of tensor products as codomains of bilinear maps but not sure how to use the universal property to demonstrate injectivity...

Comment: the linked answer deals with vector spaces, that is where the base ring is a field, so no problem . However this cannot be used to prove flatness even in this case.